# Dropbox Sharing that is Safe from Delete

Tags: dropbox

How do I share a file without others deleting it? Basically I shared a file with a client, she deleted it off her Dropbox which deleted it off of mine. How do I prevent them from having any power over the file save for safe download and still share?

Comment: Oh, Dropbox is the application. A heavy video file, so I dropboxed it.

Comment: Too big to e-mail.

Answer (score 4):

Dropbox is a file syncing service, not a file sharing with ACL service. So there's no way to prevent them from deleting, especially if you're using the Dropbox client.
It is however very easy to revert accidental file alterations (which includes deletion).
This can most easily be done on the Dropbox online control-panel for your account.

Your choices:

- Create a copy of the video file into another folder, different from the main one and share only that one.
- Tell your client not to delete the file
- Create a public link for the file & give the link rather than sharing the folder.

Comment: Creating a public link is probably the most straight-forward (at least from the sender's point of view) and would be my suggestion